# How do I seperate incoming messages from outgoing messages in FireBaseRecycler

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this chat app I'm building. But I'm stuck at this point. I have created the layouts and viewholders for the recycler view and I'm using FireBaseRecycler. But how do I seperate incoming messages from out going? How do I push incoming messages to right side and outgoing message to the left side.

Here is my layout code. The layout is inflated by the recycler

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:maxWidth="300dp"
        android:minWidth="130dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"


        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_out"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingStart="3dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout_out"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_user_out"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=" "
            android:textSize="1dp"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_text_out"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"

            android:text="hello darling how are you? How is work? hello darling how are you? How is work? hhhhhjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_time_out"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="22:30:33"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:maxWidth="300dp"
        android:minWidth="130dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_out"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_in"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingStart="3dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout_in"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_user_in"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=" "
            android:textSize="1dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_text_in"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"

            android:text="hello darling how are you? How is work? hello darling how are you? How is work? hhhhhjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_time_in"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="22:30:33"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </LinearLayout>







</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Model its a class named 'ChatMessage'

```
package com.example.stupidgeek.bboo;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by STUPID GEEK on 2/18/2019.
 */

public class ChatMessage {

    private String id;
    private String text;
    private long messageTime;
    private boolean messageTypeIn;


    public ChatMessage(String id, String text) {
        this.text = text;
        this.id = id;

        // Initialize to current time
        messageTime = new Date().getTime();
    }

    public ChatMessage(){

    }

    public String getMessageText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setMessageText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getMessageUser() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setMessageUser(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getMessageTime() {
        return messageTime;
    }

    public void setMessageTime(long messageTime) {
        this.messageTime = messageTime;
    }

    public  void setMessageTypeIn(boolean messageType)
    {
        this.messageTypeIn = messageType;

    }

    public boolean getMessageTypeIn()
    {
        return messageTypeIn;
    }

}
```

This is my chat window, the activity that displays the chats

```
package com.example.stupidgeek.bboo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.firebase.ui.database.SnapshotParser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

import java.util.List;

public class ChatWindow extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, ChatHolder> adapter;
    // private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, ChatHolderIn> adapterIn;

    ChatMessage model;
    RecyclerView list_of_messages;
    private boolean messageType = true;

    private Context mCtx;

    private List<ChatMessage> chatList;
    EditText input;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ChatMessage> options;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ChatMessage> optionsIn;
    int MessageState;
    SnapshotParser<ChatMessage>snapshotParser;
    String UserID;
    String Text;


    //getting the context and product list with constructor


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent goBack = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(goBack);
    }






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_window);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        list_of_messages = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_chat_items);

        FloatingActionButton fab =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                final FloatingActionButton fab =
                        (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "KeyboardDown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                fab.setEnabled(true);
                fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_send);
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Not Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                final String textInput = input.getText().toString();
                if ((textInput.length() == 0) || (textInput.length() < 0)) {

                    fab.setEnabled(false);
                    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_send_gray);
                    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                final FloatingActionButton fab =
                        (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "KeyboardDown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fab.setEnabled(true);
                fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_send);
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Not Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                final String textInput = input.getText().toString();
                if ((textInput.length() == 0) || (textInput.length() < 0)) {

                    fab.setEnabled(false);
                    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_send_gray);
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }


            }
        });


        String textInput = input.getText().toString();
        if ((textInput.length() == 0) || (textInput.length() < 0)) {

            fab.setEnabled(false);
            fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_send_gray);
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else {
            fab.setEnabled(true);
            fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_send);
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Not Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }


        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                // Read the input field and push a new instance
                // of ChatMessage to the Firebase database
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference().child("ebube")
                        .push()
                        .setValue(new ChatMessage(
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                                        .getCurrentUser()
                                        .getPhoneNumber(), input.getText().toString())
                        );

                // Clear the input

                input.setText("");


            }
        });


        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("ebube").orderByKey();




        if (user == null) {


//put intent to go to mainActivity

            Intent y = new Intent(ChatWindow.this, SignUpActivity.class);
            startActivity(y);

        } else {
            ///
            // User is already signed in. Therefore, display
            // a welcome Toast
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Welcome " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                            .getCurrentUser()
                            .getPhoneNumber(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            /////


            //list_of_messages.setHasFixedSize(true);
            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
            list_of_messages.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


            options =
                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
                            .setQuery(query,new SnapshotParser<ChatMessage>() {
                                @NonNull
                                @Override
                                public ChatMessage parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    return new ChatMessage(snapshot.child("messageUser").getValue().toString(),
                                            snapshot.child("messageText").getValue().toString());


                                }
                            })


                            .build();


            if (messageType) {
                messageType = false;
            } else {
                messageType = true;
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



            adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, ChatHolder>(options) {



                @Override
                public ChatHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    // Create a new instance of the ViewHolder, in this case we are using a custom
                    // layout called R.layout.message for each item


                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.chats_layout_out, parent, false);


                    return new ChatHolder(view);

                }





                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(ChatHolder holder, int position, ChatMessage model) {

                     //String ref = adapter.getRef(position).getKey();
                   // getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).child("messageUser");

                  //  Toast.makeText(ChatWindow.this, getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).child("messageUser").getValue().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    holder.layoutIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.layoutOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);




                              holder.messageTextIn.setText(model.getMessageText());
                              // holder.messageUser.setText("");

                              // Format the date before showing it
                              holder.messageTimeIn.setText(DateFormat.format("HH:mm:ss",
                                      model.getMessageTime()));

                       // ChatMessage mChat = chatList.get(position);

                        holder.messageTextOut.setText(model.getMessageText());
                       // holder.messageTextIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // holder.messageUser.setText("");


                    // Format the date before showing it
                    holder.messageTimeOut.setText(DateFormat.format("HH:mm:ss",
                            model.getMessageTime()));


                }
            };

            list_of_messages.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);


            list_of_messages.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter.startListening();


        }


    }


    class ChatHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView messageUserIn, messageTextIn, messageTimeIn, messageUserOut, messageTextOut, messageTimeOut;
        LinearLayout layoutOut;
        LinearLayout layoutIn;

        public ChatHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            messageTextIn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text_in);
            messageUserIn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user_in);
            messageTimeIn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_time_in);

            messageTextOut = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text_out);
            messageUserOut = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user_out);
            messageTimeOut = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_time_out);
            messageUserIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            messageUserOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layoutIn = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_in);
            layoutOut = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_out);


            // Set their text

        }


    }






}
```

Right now, on both sides of the chat window, the same messages are displayed regardless of the user. I'm using User phone number in place of User id.

This is what the chatroom "ebube" looks like in firebase

"ebube":{

"LZARv-CxDQ8w8mjW-mt":{

"messageText":"hi",

"messageTime":"1550675324216",

"messageUser":"+2347019081538"

}

}

I've made a lot of weak attempts, nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

make two different layouts for sender and receiver. then check if messageUser is same as logged in user or not and inflate your layouts accordingly

for Reference,look at [this](https://blog.sendbird.com/android-chat-tutorial-building-a-messaging-ui)

Comment: okay, I have two different Linear layouts inside one layout. One linear layout handles incoming messages, the other handles outgoing messages. When the layout is inflated, I set visibility of each linear layout depending on if message is incoming or not. But I cant get messageUser at a particular position.

Comment: don't you have messageUser in your ChatMessage model ??

Comment: I do, its actually Id in the message model

Comment: use that id to hide unhide your linear layout, but you really need to consider using two separate layouts if you want your messages to be left and right. refer the link to make your chat UI

Comment: I've done that, it works when the users are chatting. But when I restart the app all the messages, incoming and outgoing all move to one side. Any ideas.